# Kubernetes RBAC authentication for default user

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, kubectl, kops

I am using `kops` in AWS to create my Kubernetes cluster.

I have created a cluster with RBAC enabled via `--authorization=RBAC` as described [here.](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/cli/kops_create_cluster.md)

I am trying to use the default service account token to interact with the cluster and getting this error:

`Error from server (Forbidden): User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot list pods in the namespace "default". (get pods)`

Am I missing a role or binding somewhere?

Comment: You can check all clusterroles and clusterrolebindings by command: `kubectl get clusterrolebinding -o wide`.

Answer (score 2):

I thing it **is not a good idea** to **give the cluster-admin role to default service account in default namespace**.

If you will give cluster-admin access to default user in default namespace - **every app (pod)** that will be deployed in cluster, in default namespace - **will be able** to manipulate the cluster **(delete system pods/deployments or make other bad stuff)**.

By default the clusterrole cluster-admin is given to default service account in kube-system namespace.
You can use it for interacting with cluster.

Answer (score 0):

try to give admin role and try.

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding add-on-cluster-admin --clusterrole=cluster-admin  --serviceaccount=default:default
```